# Completely recover space from sparse bundle when "hdiutil compact" is not enough

Tags: sparsebundle

*Current situation*: I have a large sparse bundle image whose size is reported as 91GB (cmd+I from Finder). Its contents, instead, are only 80GB. `hdiutil compact` does not shrink the image:

```
Starting to compact…
Reclaiming free space…
..............................................................................
Finishing compaction…
Reclaimed 0 bytes out of 25.6 GB possible.
```

So there are 11GB of space that I cannot recover.

*How I got there*: Before getting into this situation, I had ~27GB of smallish files (MP3s, from 2-8MB) that I deleted from the image. I then ran `hdiutil compact`, but it only recovered 16GB of those 27GB, leaving 11GB of wasted space.

Any idea? Google is failing me.

Comment: From the manpage for `hdiutil`: "Depending on the location of files in the hosted filesystem", compact may or may not shrink the image. 11GB may just be worth recreating the image.

Comment: Relevant question on ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/questions/14112/how-to-reclaim-all-most-free-space-from-a-sparsebundle-on-os-x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either recreate the image, or defragment and repeat `hdiutil compact`. For defragmentation, I use [iDefrag](http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iDefrag.php).

Comment: Hmm, too bad, iDefrag's website is down and [it seems that it stopped working on 10.13.](https://web.archive.org/web/20180831134040/http://coriolis-systems.com/iDefrag/) It only supports 10.12 and earlier and has no APFS support.